# When do we say that a variable is undefined?

Tags: c, variables

In C, When do we say that a variable is undefined ? When it is not present in the complete code or in a function scope ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's declared, defined, and initialized; these terms can be applied to both functions and variables.

---

Declared means that some declaration is in scope.  For example, within some function's code, some block may contain a variable declaration, e.g. `{ extern int a, b (); }`.  Without at least a declaration, you'll get compile errors.  A declaration is nominally a reference (maybe forward) to something defined elsewhere.

---

Defined means that the authoritative definition of the variable is present somewhere; there can pretty much be only one such definition, otherwise it is an error (duplicate definition).  Declarations (alone) are not sufficient to provide a definition.  A definitions suffices for declaration (within that file).  For example, regarding the globals mentioned above, these would have to occur in the outermost scope, and without `extern`.  For the global scope, missing definitions (when declarations is present) typically results in linkage errors.

For the local scope there are few declarations (i.e. there are no forward declarations as there are with global scope) that are not also definitions, so a missing definition/declaration would result in a compile time error.

---

Initialized applies to variables, and can be present or absent at the definition (they would not be allowed in a mere declaration).  Local variables that at time of use (i.e. read) are determined to be uninitialized are typically flagged with error.  Global variables are usually not checked this way, but if an initializer is not provided it generally will get zeros or null.

---

> In C, When do we say that a variable is undefined?  When it is not present in the complete code or in a function scope?

For a global, the former: when it is not present in the complete code.  For a local, you might say in the function scope.

---

If by "is there" you mean defined, then yes, I agree.  However, a global can be declared without being defined, and then, no, we would not say it is defined, we would say it is declared or accessible.

It is generally not necessary to be this precise in most circumstances -- if we like, we can say defined or not defined when we really mean declared or not declared.  But to be precise and true to the language, we can differentiate between the two.

This terminology belongs to the language.  Another language may use different terms for the same concepts, or may have different concepts for the same terms, and, they would be inconsistent with each other, but these things do happen.

It's good for a language specification to be consistent within itself, but there's no real reason for two different languages to agree or be consistent.

Comment: If a global variable is there, then the variable is also defined, right ? I mean in static scoping if a function is not having a variable, then it will go for global variable and we will not say that variable is not defined, right ? as it is now globally defined .

Comment: I added text to respond to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

A variable is undefined when an attempt is made to access or assign it before it is declared.

This:

```
int c;
```

is a declaration.

This:

```
c = 4;
```

is an assignment.

If you do `c = 4` before `int c`, that will cause an "undefined variable" error.

You can combine declaration with assignment, as in

```
int c = 4;
```

and avoid the whole problem.

Comment: In C, a variable is also undefined if it was declared but not initialised. There is no default value provided by the compiler. Forgetting to initialise a variable before it is read from is a common source of bugs, so many static and dynamic analysis tools check for this.